# Is it possible to have left/right buttons in unsafe area next to the notch in Flutter (iOS)?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, layout

I'm currently working on my first Flutter app and now I'm trying to achieve a button next to the notch (see attached image). Placing the button at the desired place is not the problem, but the button isn't clickable. When placing the button next to the notch in a native iOS app the button is clickable. Using a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget for the buttons at the top of the screen.

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    if (widget.showMenu)
      Positioned(
        top: _iconPosition,
        left: _iconPosition + 4,
        child: CustomIconButton(
          icon: widget.menuIcon,
          width: 26,
          height: 17,
          onPressed: () => menuPressed(),
        ),
      ),
    if (widget.showLeaderboard)
      Positioned(
        top: _iconPosition,
        right: _iconPosition,
        child: CustomIconButton(
          icon: IconHelper.leaderboard,
          width: 26,
          height: 20,
          tooltip: ToolTip(icon: IconHelper.leaderboardPlus),
        ),
      ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `Stack`  widget with `SafeArea` widget with `top: true, bottom : true, right : true and legt : true`.
So you can avoid unsafe area.

Comment: I think you mean `top: false`, but no, this isn't working.